# Getting "Missing Access" error in console

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm working on an add role command in `discord.js` v13 and this is the error I am getting:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42iBG.png)

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const config = require("../../botconfig/config.json");
const ee = require("../../botconfig/embed.json");
const settings = require("../../botconfig/settings.json");

module.exports = {
  name: "addrole",
  category: "Utility",
  permissions: ["MANAGE_ROLES"],
  aliases: ["stl"],
  cooldown: 5,
  usage: "addrole <user> <role>",
  description: "Add a role to a member",

  run: async (client, message, args, plusArgs, cmdUser, text, prefix) => {

    /**
     * @param {Message} message
    */

    if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("<a:mark_rejected:975425274487398480> **You are not allowed to use this command. You need `Manage Roles` permission to use the command.**")

    const target = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (!target) return message.channel.send(`<a:mark_rejected:975425274487398480> No member specified`);
    const role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!role) return message.channel.send(`<a:mark_rejected:975425274487398480> No role specified`);

    await target.roles.add(role)
    message.channel.send(`<a:mark_accept:975425276521644102> ${target.user.username} has obtined a role`).catch(err => {
      message.channel.send(`<a:mark_rejected:975425274487398480> I do not have access to this role`)
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your error means is that your bot doesn't have permissions to give a role to a user. It might be trying to add a role which has a higher position than the bot's own role. One way to stop the error is to give the bot the highest position. The bot will also require the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission in the [Discord Developers](https://discord.com/developers) page to successfully add roles in the first place. If you want to learn more about role permissions, I suggest you go here => [Roles and Permissions](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md). Also, when you are using `.catch()` at the end, all it is checking for is if the `message.channel.send()` at the end worked and if not, then send a message to channel telling that the bot was not able to add the role. Instead you need to use `.then()` after adding the role and then use `.catch()` to catch the error. Then, your code might look like this:

```js
target.roles.add(role).then(member => {
    message.channel.send(`<a:mark_accept:975425276521644102> ${target.user.username} has obtined a role`)
}).catch(err => {
    message.channel.send(`<a:mark_rejected:975425274487398480> I do not have access to this role`)
})
```